# How to get git branch/tag names in CMake, from external project?

Tags: git, cmake

Is it possible to list all git branches or tags in cmake configure step (in ccmake/cmake-gui)?

I want to allow the user to select a specific branch/tag (available on current repository), which will be used in build (make) step for download external project.

Inital CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (project_name)

find_package (Git)
if (GIT_FOUND)
      message("git found: ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} in version     ${GIT_VERSION_STRING}")
endif (GIT_FOUND)

set (DEFAULT_TAG "tag_default")
# set (TAGS ...) getting the names of all tags from repository

set (REPO_TAG ${DEFAULT_TAG} CACHE STRING "Select a repo tag")
set_property (CACHE REPO_TAG PROPERTY STRINGS ${TAGS})

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add (
    numpy
    GIT_REPOSITORY git@bitbucket.org:pypy/numpy.git
    GIT_TAG ${REPO_TAG}
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} ls-remote
        git@bitbucket.org:pypy/numpy.git heads/*
    RESULT_VARIABLE result
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE output)
```

The commands yield a sequence of lines in the `result` variable. Each line is the hash and the full path of a branch. These lines can be processed by `string(REGEX ...)` commands to extract the branch names which can be supplied to the `set_property(CACHE <user-option-var> PROPERTY STRINGS <list-of-branches>)` command to set the options for the listbox of `<user-option-var>`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @tamas.kenez response. I created CMakeLists working for me:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (project_name)

find_package (Git)
if (GIT_FOUND)
      message("git found: ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} in version ${GIT_VERSION_STRING}")
endif (GIT_FOUND)

execute_process(
    COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:pypy/numpy.git tags/*
    RESULT_VARIABLE RESULT
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE OUTPUT)

set (DEFAULT_TAG "master")
set (REPO_TAG ${DEFAULT_TAG} CACHE STRING "Select a repo tag")

string (REGEX MATCHALL "([^/]+)[\^{}]\n" TAGS ${OUTPUT})
string (REGEX REPLACE "\n" ";"  TAGS ${TAGS})
set_property (CACHE REPO_TAG PROPERTY STRINGS ${TAGS})

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add (
    numpy
    GIT_REPOSITORY git@bitbucket.org:pypy/numpy.git
    GIT_TAG "${REPO_TAG}"
)
```